# Adding a new humanities tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging, tag-cleanup-proposal

I added a new [humanities](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humanities) tag.

I was about to retag a few questions every day so I don't bump-flood the landing page, which I dimly remembered to be accepted practice - when it occurred to me to look at what accepted practice actually *is*. And I learned that [I should submit a list of the questions I'd retag for community discussion and subsequent all-at-once retagging](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1266/4140).

So, these are the questions I already tagged [humanities](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humanities):

- [More co-authored than solo papers in the Humanities](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38743/more-co-authored-than-solo-papers-in-the-humanities)
- [What tense to use in arts and humanities papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18146/4140)
- [How does an engineering undergraduate apply for master in humanities?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/14968/4140)

And here are the other candidates I'd retag:

- [What computations of the Lotka function exist for publications in humanities meta-disciplines?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10010/4140)
- [What is the equivalent of the laboratory notebook in the humanities?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1301/4140)
- [How to pursue graduate admissions in mathematics seven years after a humanities undergrad degree?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13119/4140)
- [What are the main factors that mean Humanities PhDs get published as books?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/35254/4140)
- [Fast academic publishing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16446/4140)
- [Post tenure job search a waste of time?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/26698/4140)
- [Why Are Linguistics and Law “Sciences”?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/19584/4140)
- [Is it good practice to let students consult their text materials during exams?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17763/4140)
- [What is the best way to go about doing research as an undergrad (pointed question inside)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/24106/4140)
- [How to make academic life bearable under stressing circumstances?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/20214/4140)

The other hits from [my search](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=humanities+is%3Aquestion) did not seem to warrant retagging.

So, let's discuss. How about I mass-retag all these in two days, unless vocal opposition arises? (Or perhaps mods have tools to do this?)

Any other questions that could benefit from this retag would also be helpful. For instance, as you see, I only searched for "humanities", not the specific humanities.

---

EDIT: I looked through our tags and didn't find anything else that looked like it needed retagging [humanities](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humanities). For now, I edited the tag wiki as per [@ff524's suggestion](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/4140). I'll do the retagging when I find the time - hopefully on the weekend, otherwise on Monday morning.

Comment: I think you might be the first person to try this proposal, so lets see how it goes.

Comment: I don't see a problem with this proposal, or the list of questions to be tagged.

Comment: This looks like a good idea.

Comment: I like the idea of having this new tag on Academia website. Thank you for proposing it.

Answer (score 4):

I like the tag. I would like to see more representation from the humanities on Academia.SE and a tag is a nice way of showing how welcome this would be.

I have a few comments about its implementation.

About the tag wiki excerpt: The other 'displine' tags typically say,

> On standards or conventions specific to X as an academic discipline, and programs that lead to a degree in this field.

I like this convention, partly because it clarifies what questions are on topic. People say, "I should be able to ask this math question here, because there's a [mathematics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) tag" and it's nice to be able to show them that the tag is for questions "On standards or conventions specific to mathematics as an academic discipline, and programs that lead to a degree in this field." not questions on mathematics.

All of that was a long way of saying that maybe the tag wiki excerpt should say

> On standards or conventions specific to the humanities, i.e. the academic disciplines that study human culture, and programs that lead to a degree in these fields. Examples include ancient and modern languages, literature, philosophy, religion, and visual and performing arts such as music and theatre.

I also have some comments about a few of the proposed retags. Not that I think any of them are *wrong*, but I think a few of them could do without the [humanities](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humanities) tag for various reasons. Also, for a few of them, I would suggest making the most of the edit/bump by also fixing some other things (specifics as follows).

- [How to pursue graduate admissions in mathematics seven years after a humanities undergrad degree?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13119/how-to-pursue-graduate-admissions-in-mathematics-seven-years-after-a-humanities)
  When tagging [changing-fields](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changing-fields) questions, lately I've been leaving out the 'original field' tag and only using the 'destination field' tag. The reason for this is twofold: 1) these questions tend to already have many tags, so sometimes there isn't room for both tags, and even in cases where there *is* room I don't like that we can't consistently tag with both fields. 2) These questions are really about standards and conventions in the destination field, not the original field, i.e. they need expertise from someone in the destination field, expertise in the conventions of the original field is not really required. Others may disagree with me on this...
- On [How to get my humanities paper published in the short timeframe before admissions deadline?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16446/fast-academic-publishing), I would suggest making the most of the edit/bump by also editing the title to be more representative of the actual question: "How to get my humanities paper published in the short timeframe before admissions deadline?" (and also add the [deadlines](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadlines) tag)
- I don't think [Why are linguistics and law "sciences"?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19584/why-are-linguistics-and-law-sciences) needs a [humanities](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humanities) tag - it's more about what's considered [science](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science). (The only reason it turned up in a search for 'humanities' is because the OP wrote "humanities" instead of what he really meant to say, "humanity's".) It does need the [law](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) and [linguistics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) tags, whether or not [humanities](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humanities) is also added :)
- In [Post tenure job search in the humantities: a waste of time?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26698/post-tenure-job-search-a-waste-of-time), I would suggest also editing the title to be explicit about the field ("Post tenure job search in the humanities...")
- I don't think [How to make academic life bearable under stressing circumstances?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20214/how-to-make-academic-life-bearable-under-stressing-circumstances) is specific to humanities. As far as I can tell, the question and answers apply broadly. (It could use the [academic-life](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-life) tag, though)

Comment: Lots of good points, thanks - I will do so.