# Can visibility and responsiveness of tag warnings be improved?

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

As per [this feature request](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1886/for-which-tags-if-any-do-we-want-tag-warnings) we now have a warning for the [graduate-admissions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate-admissions) tag.

I'm happy for the warning, and I thank all those who have contributed, but I'm concerned by its low visibility. Most people, I suspect, add tags after having written the question. I tried, and I got this:

[image]

The tag is in the lower right corner and not fully readable. In addition, the tag warning appeared much later than the tag, which means I'd have had all the time to click on the "Post Your Question" button, without ever getting the warning.

1. Could the warning be placed in a more central position?
2. Could the delay between the tag placement and the appearance of the warning be reduced?